# react-native Slider inside a ScrollView (android only)

Tags: android, react-native, slider, scrollview

Has anybody been able to make a `Slider` work when embedded inside a `ScrollView`? Just like everything else in `react-native`, this works flawlessly on `iOS` but not on `Android`.

FWIW, tapping on the `Slider` seems to work but sliding it does not.

Both `@react-native-community/slider` & `react-native-elements` have the same problem.

**Working example**

```
import React from 'react';
import type {Node} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Dimensions
} from 'react-native';
import Slider from '@react-native-community/slider';

const Volume = ({children, title}): Node => {
  return (
    <Slider
    style={{width: 200, height: 40}}
    minimumValue={0}
    maximumValue={1}
    minimumTrackTintColor="#FFFFFF"
    maximumTrackTintColor="#000000"
  />
  );
};

const App: () => Node = () => {
  const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
  const slideStyle = { width, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 } }>
      <ScrollView horizontal pagingEnabled removeClippedSubviews={false}>
        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red', ...slideStyle}}><Volume /></View>
        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'blue', width, ...slideStyle}}><Volume /></View>
        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'green', width, ...slideStyle}}><Volume /></View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: What is the component or module of your slider component? it is Scrollview? please add more code to be clear.

Comment: Choice of slider component doesn't matter but I've updated the post. I'm also working on a test application and will add code to the post. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't use any of them before, but I use multi-slider `@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider` inside scroll view, and it works fine.

Comment: same issue in Flutter, also on Android only.